# How can I transfer a large number of big files over local network with pause/resume support?

Tags: networking, ftp, router, local-area-network, file-transfer

My MacBook has about 400GB of files (videos, music, documents, etc.) that I need to transfer to a Windows PC over my local network. My router is semi-disfunctional, though, so every so often it stops working and I have to unplug it and plug it back in.

How can I copy the files so that the transfer will resume after the network connection has been reestablished? Will FTP/SSH/SMB work, if I have the right type of client? It would also be nice if I could resume the transfer when I reboot one of the machines while I'm transferring, too.

Comment: Please don't be offended that we closed your question. [SF] is a community by and for System Administrators only. Your question is from the prospective of a typical user and would be completely appropriate for our [Su] or [Apple.se] sites. Please have a look at their and our [FAQ] before posting. Thank you and have a nice day!

Answer (score 3):

You want rsync over SSH. Look at using `--partial`.